# Laravel: Access collection in view

Tags: laravel, collections, view

I would like to display users that have sent or got message/s.

User Model:

```php
public function messages_sender()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'sender_id');
}

public function messages_recipient()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'recipient_id');
}
```

MessageController

```php
public function index()
{
    $users = User::with('messages_recipient', 'messages_sender')->paginate(5);
    //return $users;
    return view('message.index',compact('users'));
}
```

Messages View:

```php
{{ $user->messages_recipient['recipient_id'] }}
```

Result is an error in view "Undefined index: recipient_id" or when i try to access any of them (sender_id, recipient_id). I understand that not all users have messages, as i see in JSON format, so i used:

```php
@if($user->messages_recipient->has('recipient_id'))
    {{ $user->messages_recipient['recipient_id'] }}
@endif
```

and than error did not show.

JSON: https://pastebin.com/NFSWMp7r

As I am new to Laravel i could use some help. In similar example it worked when I needed to get users and name of their role (admin, user).

Answer (score 0):

Your using the message_recipient as an array and if a key doesn't exist on an array PHP will always throw an error. The hasMany relationship returns a Collection of Message objects so you would need to use it as an object with:

```
@foreach($user->messages_sender as $message)   
    {{ $message->id }}
@endforeach
```

and

```
@foreach($user->messages_recipient as $message)   
    {{ $message->id }}
@endforeach
```

or if you just wanted all of the message ids you could do `$user->messsages_recipient->pluck('id')` and that would return all of the ids of the Message objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Users form the `App\Message` Model instead of the other way round.

Message Model:

```
public function senders()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Users', 'sender_id');
}
```

Message Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $senders = Message::senders()->paginate(5);

    return view('message.index',compact('senders'));
}
```

Dont blame me but I am not sure, if the `sender_id` is just right there :-P

Unfortunately, if you want unique records this will not work.